# How to efficiently create a list of objects inside of a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, ado.net

So, I have an application which lies on a database. So far, the results of my queries all went into a DataTable object like this:

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Load(someQuery.ExecuteReader());
```

Now, I want to load my data into a list of a strongly typed objects. Something like this:

```
List<MyClass> data = someQuery.Load<MyClass>();
```

However, my first take on writing that method ended up running almost three times slower than DataTable.Load(IDataReader) method. Basically, I have user GetConstructor(null).Invoke(null) to create and object and I have used PropertyInfo.SetValue(reader.GetValue()) to fill it with data.

Is there a better way to do this?

The method used:

```
    public List<T> LoadData<T>(DbCommand query)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        using (IDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                T newObject = (T)t.GetConstructor(null).Invoke(null);

                for (int ct = 0; ct < reader.FieldCount; ct++)
                {
                    PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty(reader.GetName(ct));
                    if (prop != null)
                        prop.SetValue(newObject, reader.GetValue(ct), null);
                }

                list.Add(newObject);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Reflection no doubt is slow. By strongly typed you mean `MyClass` always or it can be any type say `T`? Can you post code for loading to a list of strongly typed objects?

Comment: Any class can be used. Class properties has to match the data of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this efficiently requires metaprogramming. You can use libraries to help. For example, "FastMember" includes a TypeAccessor which provides fast access to instance creation and member-access by name. However, this example is also basically exactly how "dapper" works, so you could just *use dapper*:

```
int id = ...
var data = connection.Query<Order>(
    "select * from Orders where CustomerId = @id",
    new { id }).ToList();
```

You can also open up the "dapper" code to see what it does.

Comment: Never knew it existed. The author claims speed, I'll put it to test.

Comment: @Nezreli yes, I do claim speed :) we wrote dapper here at Stack Exchange specifically with performance as the key measure. We optimized it until it squeaked, basically - because we do "quite a lot" of data access.

Comment: Thanks. I'm facing a 300M+ table. I'll need all the help I can get to manage it.

Comment: @Nezreli I assume you have a good reason to load 300M into memory. That is not the usual case, though.

Comment: No, no need to load that much at once. The challenge is to enable 200+ users to work on it without hiccups.

Comment: @Nezreli even with 200+ users, that doesn't usually mean "load all the data" - as an example, Stack Overflow has a lot more users than that - but we don't load the entire DB. But: I'll assume you have a design that needs that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your query using linQ and get the Generic List and then if you want to conver it to DataTable then use the following Code, it may help you.

```
public DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

it will work for any strongly type class. Please check the time it takes to execute.

Thanks,